# Slide Div In and Out at the same time

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an effect such that when a link is clicked the div on the page slides out to the left, and the linked div slides in from the left just as : http://templates.entheosweb.com/template_number/live_demo.asp?TemplateID=38272

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Have you tried something or still nothing?

Comment: got this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/538/....

Comment: What is the issue then?  Seems to work as described above...

Comment: all the links are not working as desired.....every time div1 is replaced by div4 and vice versa. links for div2 and div3 are not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @SeaMirra said, try to use the callback function of the .animate().
Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/5677/

```
 $('.button a').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var tg = $(this).attr('href');
     tg = tg.substr(1, tg.length); /* Get the target ID */
     $('.current').animate({'left' : '-50%'}, 500, function(){
         $('.current').removeClass('current');
         $('#' + tg).addClass('current').animate({'left' : '50%'}, 500);
     });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, the part with the substr is absolutely nonsense in this case, because there are separate id's (I'm used to use this in cases where I have some other things). So this is better: http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/5680/ . but the animate part is the same :)

Answer (score 2):

if you change your html to the following (moved classes to the anchors and given them an actual href - helps with accessibility and will jump users without js to the correct area):

```
<div><a href="#box1" class="button">Click Box #1</a> </div>
<div><a href="#box2" class="button">Click Box #2</a> </div>
<div><a href="#box3" class="button">Click Box #3</a> </div>
<div><a href="#box4" class="button">Click Box #4</a> </div>

<div id="container">
    <div id="box1" class="box">Box #1</div>
    <div id="box2" class="box">Box #2</div>
    <div id="box3" class="box">Box #3</div>
    <div id="box4" class="box">Box #4</div>
</div>
```

you can use the following js:

```
var boxes = $('.box'),
    currentBox = 1;

$('.button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var box = $($(this).attr('href'));
    if (box.css("left") == "150%") {
        $('#box' + currentBox).stop().animate({left: '150%',}, 500 );
        box.stop().animate({left: '50%',}, 500 );
        currentBox = boxes.index(box) + 1;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/5678/

or using classes:

http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/5681/

Answer (score 1):

Jquery's animate function should do what you need. You can use it to animate the css "left" property from a negative (hidden) value to a positive (visible) value.

http://jsfiddle.net/xPEP2/

```
    $('something').click(function() {
  $('div').animate({
    left: 0,
  }, 1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Good Luck!

Comment: @Seer gave an incredibly detailed answer and fiddle, kudos, seems like s/he did most of the work for you :)